# Can I avoid to include <iostream> if I do not use its functions?

Tags: c++, debugging, optimization, c-preprocessor, iostream

I would like to optimise this code:

```
#include <iostream>

#define LOG if(true) {} else std::cerr

LOG << "test" << std::endl;
```

Since the compiler does not ignore the else block, and requires `<iostream>` to be included, can I use a "cheaper" function compared to `std::cerr`, including a simpler header compared to `<iostream>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
#ifdef DO_LOG
    #include <iostream>
    #define LOG std::cerr
#else
    class nullstr {};
    template<typename T>
    nullstr operator<<(nullstr s, T const&) { return s; }

    #define LOG if (false) nullstr()
#endif
```

The code under the `if` will be compiled, but not executed.

This "null stream" is rather badly implemented, though, with a few problems (e.g. can't use `std::endl`). There's a much better implementation in Boost available, but I doubt pulling in Boost for such a simple feature makes sense.

Comment: Do you know which part of Boost? Maybe I can extract the code I need from there, without having to include anything else...

Comment: @Pietro Start looking [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/null.html).

Answer (score 0):

> Can I avoid to include  if I do not use its functions?

No. Not using functions isn't sufficient.

Besides, not using functions, you must also not use other declarations such as variables (such as `std::cerr`), templates and types. Also, "using" in this context means any mention of the declared identifiers - just because a particular branch won't be taken at runtime doesn't mean that the code doesn't need to be well formed. A few templates are declared in `<iosfwd>` and can thus be used in limited ways without including their definiton.

> I would like to optimise this code:

Your program has no runtime behaviour, so you can optimise it to:

```
// nothing
```